# How to generate REST API for related entities in #jhipster Microservices?

Tags: rest, jhipster

Basically I can do this by creating a custom method in Rest resources but,

what I wanted to know if there is a configuration which could allow generating Rest API's for all entites with their related entites being returned in same call?

For instance, I have a **Customer** entity which has OneToMany relationship with **Account** entity.

When I call the **getCustomer** interface it only returns the attributes from Customer entity and not the Acccount entites which are linked to Customer.

Also in the generated Mapper from jhipster, I can see that **@Mapping** is having **ignore=true** attribute specified for Account entity.

Is it possible to **load all related entities for the main entity by just changing some sort of configuration in the application**?

Answer (score 2):

JHipster generates JPA entities with lazy-loaded relations and ignore related objects in JSON serialization.

So the only solution for your use case is to modify the generated code.

You could change annotations in entities to turn off lazy loading for some relations, and change JSON annotations in DTOs to include related object or add some REST methods or parameters to control when you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I run into similar problem recently using JHipster 3.x.

The simple fix I did is simply adding fetch=FetchType.EAGER (this will actually fix LazyInitializationException) to @OneToMany annotation, i.e.
in your case, Customer class should have something like

```
...
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer" )
    private Set<Account> accounts = new Set<Account>();

    ...

}
```

Change that @OneToMany to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE )
private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Note the addition of cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE will allow you to cascade delete of a customer to all accounts attached to the 
customer automatically!

**Pitfall I found with this approach:**

- If your Account JPA also has a @ManyToOne mapping to Customer
  instance variable, make sure you add @JsonIgnore to it else infinite
  recursion of JSON response can happen when calling rest to access
  an Account data. Why? JSON response from rest Account will contain
  Customer data which will then contain accounts, which will then
  contain customer, which will then contain ... you get the point and the page freeze ;)
- Data returned from calling rest Account service(the one generated by
  JHipster) won't contain Customer data because of the fix above.
- Better remove @Cache added in accounts List above in Customer class if any. Else u can expect JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException as result of

  1. load the Customer 1st then
  2. deleting an Account record of the customer then
  3. accessing the Customer again

  Exception happens since step 1 will cache account as result of @Cache
  so step 3 will try to retrieve the deleted account again(remember
  eager loading above), boooom.

Hope this helps.